# intelliJ IDEA: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, runtime

I'm using Intellij IDEA and getting this error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: siimport.Pres
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

My code is,

```
package si;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Pres
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("kk.data"));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("samlog.csv"));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] values =line.split(" ", -1);
            bw.write(values[0] + "," + values[3] + "," + values[5] + "\", "+values[6]+ "," + values[8] + "\n");
        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

What could be the problem which is resulting this error and how can I resolve?

I also made this screenshot:
[image: Check this Image]

Comment: This code seems not to throw such exception. You are running this code using another class? Because your error log says `com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)` and it seems there is something wrong with your compilation or building phase and it cannot find your compiled class to run.

Comment: How can I sove this problem @Staefi

Comment: Does your real code has such package declaration with syntax error: `papackage si;` ?

Comment: There is no problem with that.

Comment: so please edit you question's code to correct `papackage si;` to `package si;`

Comment: I think it cannot find the compiled class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

In the run/debug configuration you have written wrong class name for the *Main class* field. The name of the class should be the class that has `main` method to run.

This error could also happen if you didn't create or didn't select run/debug configuration for the class. To create it use *Edit Configurations* -> *Add new* under application tree item or from the editor press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>hift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and choose your file to run. The configuration will be added automatically. To select current run/debug configuration use dropdown from the toolbar.

Usually I prefer to choose from menu *Run* -> *Run*, but as @Bajal mentioned in the comment, you can right-click on the file from the *Project Structure* and choose *Run* from the popup menu or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: I saved file as **Pres.java** but on pressing your suggested keys it is showing _Main_ and why it is not showing _Pres_

Comment: I just created the file and running as it is. But, Where does the problem persisting as you said first.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the file (either in project view, or in the editor window) and choosing run?

Comment: what is the folder name where the file is?

Comment: The folder name is **src**

Comment: Then you should remove the first line

Comment: If I remove the first line same exception is occuring with _si.Pres_

Comment: If you removed first line there's no `si` token anymore, but you didn't and it's not java project or deleted altogether without java compiler.

Comment: @Raghu This is already another question or I missed something? You messed up package name.

Answer (score 4):

Just as an aside, I was having this problem and resolved it as the run configuration was using 
"Use Classpath of module" ProjectName

i changed it from that to

"Use Classpath of module" ProjectName_main

and that made it work - I personally do not like how they have added these sub modules but i guess if you are using stuff like gradle/maven you will have to put up with it in Intellij.